# Use python and pandas to set key for imported data from text file to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This feels like an incredibly straight forward problem, but I am new and stuck, apologies.

It doesn't necessarily *need* a key, but that was how I thought to solve it.

I have a text file whose abbreviated contents resemble this:

name_of_source

128 1024.000000 225.569918

name_of_source_2

140 1120.000000 229.085200

etc etc

I really need the output dataframe to resemble:

name_of_source 128 1024.000000 225.569918

name_of_source_2 140 1120.000000 229.085200

I'm struggling to overcome the linebreak between the name and the data

```
import pandas as pd
import os



data= pd.read_csv(path+'combined.txt', header=None, sep = "\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+", names='name vol1 vol2 vol3'.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df= pd.read_csv("test.txt", header=None)

out= (
        df.rename(columns= {0: "Name"})
          .join(df.shift(-1).rename(columns={0: "Vals"}))
          .iloc[::2]
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
               Name                        Vals
0    name_of_source  128 1024.000000 225.569918
2  name_of_source_2  140 1120.000000 229.085200
```

If need separate values, use [**`pandas.Series.str.split`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
print(pd.concat([out, out.pop("Vals").str.split(expand=True).add_prefix('Vals_')], axis=1))

               Name Vals_0       Vals_1      Vals_2
0    name_of_source    128  1024.000000  225.569918
2  name_of_source_2    140  1120.000000  229.085200
```

##### # .txt used:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help here - I'm getting 'df is not defined' - are you defining it prior to this snippet?

Comment: Oops, you're right. I updated my answer ;)